# Necessity of World splitting in Many-World-Formalism

Tags: quantum-interpretations

I am reading descriptions about many world formalism, where the idea of "one wavefunction for the whole universe" makes sense to me. Everything goes so well until I read the "world splitting part":

I do not understand the necessity for "splitting world". It seems plausible to me if someone claims there exists a Hamiltonian for how everything evolves in our universe(including measurement). *

*Why exactly do we need "world splitting" in the Many-World-Formalism? How exactly is world-splitting part "programmed" into Many-World-Formalism?*

---

*Finding it, however, seems almost impossible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During measurement, the quantum state non-unitarily 'collapses' into an Eigenstate of the observable under consideration. In the Many Worlds interpretation, that collapse is only apparent, and all other Eigenstates with non-zero expansion coefficients correspond to equally real 'worlds' where the measurement yielded a different result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind elaborating more about how  "Eigenstates with non-zero expansion coefficients correspond to equally real 'worlds'"?

Comment: @Shing: prepare your cat-killing device in a superposition of states $|a\rangle + |b\rangle$, or rather $(|a\rangle + |b\rangle)\otimes|\text{live cat}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world 0}\rangle$, which evolves into $|a\rangle\otimes|\text{live cat}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world 1}\rangle + |b\rangle\otimes|\text{dead cat}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world 2}\rangle$; without collapse, both of these 'branches' are equally real

Comment: So basically, in a two-slits experiment, we are in a overlap of $|right\rangle +|left\rangle$ (and such overlap has interference), a measurement separates two worlds, and we have to be in one of world (interference disappear). Is my impression correct?

Comment: @Shing: yes, that's it

Answer (score 1):

Its true that the splitting part seems unnecessary. However, it *is* necessary in that it can be used as an explanation for why a coherent process apparently accounts for those states that were never measured. For example, consider a process where there is a finite chance one state can change to either of two states, and then either of those two states can then become the *same* third state, and it all happens coherently. Many worlds shows how both paths contribute to the probability of arriving at the final state. Specifically, many worlds includes combining as well as splitting.